# jQuery regex help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to take a string of text

```
var myText = $(this).text();
```

which looks something like this

```
<my text (10)>
```

and strip down all but numeric value. I tried this but failed:

```
var myNum = myText.match(/<.*\(|\)>/);
```

Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myNum = myText.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
```

EDIT:

```
var myNum = myText.match(/\(([0-9]+)\)/)[1];
```

Comment: Dah... I'm thinking backwards sometimes... Perfect! thanks. What's that "g" there for? Just curious.

Comment: You can also use `/\D/g` or `/\D+/g`, it should be just the same (in JavaScript)

Comment: g flag is to replace globally. Without it the replace would stop after first matched item.

Comment: Woops, just tested with the following <my text 5 (10)> and instead of getting 10 I got 5... So, it does have to be in () at the end of the string... Sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
var myNum = myText.match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1];
```